# MySQL Query: Select Most

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a table sorted like this:

```
id    tag    account
 0    sport     123
 1    game      123
 2    sport     123
 3    game      234
 4    sport     234
 5    game      234
```

Is there a way to get all rows with tag sport and sort them by which account has the most entries? I feel like it should be pretty simple. Actually, all I want is distinct accounts sorted by which one has the most entries for sport? I'd appreciate any help I could get.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you what you "actually" want:

> Actually, all I want is distinct accounts sorted by which one has the most entries for sport

```
select account from table
where tag = 'sport'
group by account
order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: Excellent, I knew I was looking to use order by and group by, just wasn't sure how to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it.

```
SELECT account, COUNT(account) AS 'c'
FROM sports
WHERE tag = 'sport'
GROUP BY account
ORDER BY c DESC;
```

Comment: The `'c'` should be without quotes: `c`

Comment: @ypercube can't try it right now, but I am pretty sure, it doesn't matter. Although I also wouldn't use quotes

Comment: @tombom: You are right, it probably does work in MySQL. That doesn't make it proper use though :)

Comment: @ypercube the best way to use in MySQL is using `backquotes` to avoid mixing up with reserved words